# Ubuntu : dpkg --add-architecture i386 throwing error --add-architecture unknown option

Tags: ubuntu, architecture, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I want to enable extra architecture (of 32-bit) in my 64 bit machine . I did *dpkg --print-architecture* to know the already known architecture i.e.amd64 . After that I did *dpkg --print--foreign-architectures* and got the result as i386(I want to enable this) . But when i typed *dpkg --add-architecture i386* , it is throwing an error saying that unknown option -add-architecture ? Please suggest some solutions for this .

I refer this link by the way : https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO

Answer (score 6):

There is no `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/architectures` file in Ubuntu 12.04.So the below command will works,

```
echo "foreign-architecture i386" > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
```

OR

```
sudo dpkg --foreign-architecture i386
```

Answer (score 2):

echo "foreign-architecture i386" > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/architectures

Answer (score 0):

just need a simple word as the beginning of the command line, there is not a single order for command prompt, there are two, you need to authenticate the root user in both as
sudo echo "foreign-architecture i386" > sudo /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
this solve the error, that is so simple