# Cannot install any package in Ubuntu using dpkg, getting "package architecture does not match system"

Tags: ubuntu

Whenever I want to upgrade or install any package on Ubuntu 16.04 this error appears!

> dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-6-base_6.0.1-ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
>
> package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)
>
> Errors were encountered while processing:
>
> /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-6-base_6.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
>
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

The uname command outputs as follows:

```
uname -i
x86_64

uname -a
Linux hossein 4.4.0-138-generic #164-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 2 17:16:02 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: try first `sudo apt-get clean all` and `sudo apt-get update` the you can try to install the i386 not sure why is trying to install the 64bit.

Comment: Did not work! 
`> uname -i
x86_64`

Answer (score 3):

Try to run this commands to enable support for the 64-bit userspace.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64
sudo apt-get update
```

and try to install the packages again. Also,you could try to run

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

to move the investigation further.

Comment: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64`
get the following error:
`dpkg: error: unknown option --add-architecture`

Comment: Try following the instructions on this threads: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462579/ubuntu-dpkg-add-architecture-i386-throwing-error-add-architecture-unknown) and (https://askubuntu.com/questions/423083/cant-run-dpkg-add-architecture-i386-on-12-04-64-bit-to-run-eclipse-adt). Remember that you're trying to add the amd64 architecture, so adapt the solution to your own needs.

Comment: The second one worked but another error occured:
`dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_9.4ubuntu4.8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 pre-dependency problem - not installing base-files:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_9.4ubuntu4.8_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
`

Comment: Finally, I had to install my ubuntu again! :(

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Feel free to answer your own question with detail of your progress and mark it as solved so other users can follow your steps as well!

Answer (score 0):

Your processor, as quoted, works on a different architecture than the one provided by the binary inside the package. To work around this problem, you could:

- Download a compatible stable version, one that does run in a i386 architecture ([you can download the package here](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/16.04/ubuntu-main-i386/gcc_5.3.1-1ubuntu1_i386.deb.html)) or...
- Download, compile and run the source code ([suggested download here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gccgo-6/6.0.1-0ubuntu1)).

As you trying to install GCC, a simple

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

should work from the latest stable version. If you keep getting erros, try checking this threads:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/778318/how-do-i-install-gcc-6-latest-6-1-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-make-c14-the-default
https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-on-ubuntu

Comment: Not solved!  I can not install any package on my system. that error occurs.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you getting exactly the `package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)` error regardless of the package you're trying to install?

Comment: Yes exactly! @evandro-teixeira

Comment: Please, add to the body of your question (using the edit tool) the outputs of the following commands: `uname -i ` and `uname -a`. Also, try checking this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/276700/error-package-architecture-amd64-does-not-match-system-i386

Comment: please join all your insights/recommendations into one solution instead of 2